# Get elements by class name after Handlebars template is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get elements by class name, but get empty array.
Here is a simple code I use, it's just shows names from the list.

```
<html>
      <head>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
          <script id="test" type="text/template">
              <div>
                {% raw %}
                  {{#each users}}
                      <li class="user">{{this}}</li>
                  {{/each}}
                {% endraw %}
              </div>
          </script>

          <script>
              const template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML);

              document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                      var users = ['Bob', 'Nick', 'Alice', 'Brian'];
                      const content = template({'users': users});
                      document.querySelector('#users_list').innerHTML = content;
              });
              var list = document.getElementsByClassName('user');
              console.log(list);
          </script>

      </head>
      <body>
          <ul id="users_list">
          </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
```

So after I run the code , console.log(list) show an empty array.
But if I put 'document.getElementsByClassName('user');' in console I get an array with 4 elements as expected.

Seems like at the moment I call console.log(list), the elements haven't been loaded yet.

**What I've already tried:**

1. Use jquery which returns same empty list

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('user');
    console.log(list)
});
```

2. Run function which templates Handlebars and then run 'document.getElementsByClassName('user')'
   `$.when(function1()).then(function())`

**Expected result** - get an array with 4 objects

How to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are listening event, which will trigger after you code below.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the event listener is running *after* you query the elements with the `user` class, so when you do it, there aren't any.

Try inserting the code inside the listener or get rid of the listener completely.

```
<script>
    const template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML);

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var users = ['Bob', 'Nick', 'Alice', 'Brian'];
        const content = template({'users': users});
        document.querySelector('#users_list').innerHTML = content;

        var list = document.getElementsByClassName('user');
        console.log(list);
    });
</script>
```